# Unable to get latest updates using apt-get update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, dpkg

Installed Jenkins 2.19 a while ago using apt-get install by adding the following sources https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/

Source list file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list has the following content

```
deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/
```

Output for **apt-cache policy jenkins** is like

```
Installed: 2.19.3
  Candidate: 2.73.2
  Version table:
     2.73.2 0
        500 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ Packages
     2.73.1 0
        500 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ Packages
     2.60.3 0
        500 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ Packages
        500 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ Packages
     2.60.2 0
        500 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ Packages
     2.60.1-1 0
        500 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ Packages
     2.60.1 0
        500 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ Packages
     2.46.2 0
        500 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ Packages
     2.46.1 0
        500 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ Packages
     2.32.3 0
        500 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ Packages
     2.32.2 0
        500 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ Packages
     2.32.1 0
        500 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ Packages
     2.19.4 0
        500 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ Packages
 *** 2.19.3 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

which means there are more updated versions to install, So if i do a **apt-get update** i should expect my Jenkins version to be 2.73.2 but it is not, why isn't that happening.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

First run **apt-get update**, then run **apt-get upgrade**.

- **apt-get update** updates your package manager with the lists of all available packages and their version, but it doesn't install or upgrade packages.
- **apt-get upgrade** actually installs the newer versions. After you've updated the lists, your package manager knows about available updates and can then be upgraded.

Hope that helps.